# How use restrictions column as where of query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

There's a way to use information of one column as restriction for where in the same query? Picture that:

I have my `user_table` like so:

| user_id | name | age | gender | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 36 | male | 17 |
| 2 | ASh | 34 | female | 19 |

And other table called `services` like so:

| service_id | name | restrictions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | service 1 | 'gender' = 'male', 'age' > 18 |
| 2 | service 2 | 'gender' = 'female' |

There is a way to do in one query a request that i just pass the user_id and its return all services that user is eligible based on restrictions of service table, i tried to do that using JS but would like to know if there is a way to do this in SQL because i believe to do more performatic.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes it can be done.

```
create or replace 
function user_service_with_restructions(service_id_in integer) 
 returns setof user_table 
 language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
   l_query_base   text = 'select * from user_table where '; 
   l_restrictions text ;
begin   
   select restrictions 
     into l_restrictions
     from services 
    where service_id = service_id_in; 

   return query execute l_query_base || l_restrictions;  
end; 
$$;
```

But it falls into the category: "Just because you can do something does not mean you should".
What this is doing is storing the where clause. That makes it subject all kinds of complications. Not the least of which are:

- It is subject to **SQL injection**. Not directly so much but in creating
  the restrictions column. Extreme care must be taken there.
- The restrictions column must form a valid where clause, failure to
  do so introduces extremely hard to find errors. So again extreme care must be taken there. Note: Do not quote column names.
- The above is a very minimalist function which could become much
  more complicated depending on the content of restrictions column.
- Others ???

See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ccec03c3ff453d53752f5923fab40697).

The outstanding question: Will it perform better. Well the answer there is a definite *maybe*.